# how to fetch particular elements from two same type[string] of different list and stored it into another list?

Tags: c#, list

In project list elements are pid,pname,pdate....and another list is employee list which contains eid,ename,eadress

now i want to add employee list elements to particular project list element and it should be added in 3rd list

for example whenever i select option to add employee to project it will ask enter pid, then eid and refering this input its should fetch the data from two same type of different list and store into another list and data will be pid, eid, pname, ename, pdate

i am using switch case for option....its a simple task

i wnated to do it in simple logic using for loop or something else

note: Data is not connected with database yet....

i am new in c#

```
    private List<Model> projectVariables { get; set; } = new 
        List<Model>();
    private List<Model> EmployeeVariable { get; set; } = new 
         List<Model>();
    private List<Model> proemp { get; set; } = new 
         List<Model>();

     public void AddProjectEmployee(Model proemp)
         {
            if (projectVariables.Any() && EmployeeVariable.Any())
              {
                 Proemp.Add(proemp);
              }
         }
        public void  DisplayProjectEmployee()
            {
               foreach (var project in projectVariables)
                  {
                  Console.WriteLine($" Id= |{project.PId}| Name= | 
                 {project.PName}| Start Date= |{project.PStartDate}|");
                   }
               foreach (var employee in EmployeeVariable)
               {
                Console.WriteLine($": ID= |{employee.EID}| First Name= | 
                {employee.EFName}| Last Name= |{employee.ELName}|");
               }       
          }
```

i am trying like this dont know whether its correct or not

Comment: Will you please share the code that you have tried, we are here to help with your issues not to provide solutions. One thing you can do, when you get the pid and eid, find the relative object from both lists and create an Entity with ProjectEmployeeMapping containing the new list fields. It will be easy to help if you have a code with you

Comment: yes added @Sandeep Kokate

Comment: I can't see how your models are the same. ProjectId/EmployeeId yes, then look like ints or guides, I would t mix em but it's your code not mine. ProjectName/EmployeeName look like strings so that's possibly ok too. ProjectDate/EmployeeAddress seems completely unrelated, not even the same data type. Explain how you want to fit these quarts into the same pint pot?